# How to mock methods which has defined/fixed/hardcoded input?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

I have a method in a class lets say doStuff which calls another method of another class execute:

```
@Component
class A {
 @Autowired
 B b;
 int doStuff(){
  return b.execute(1);
 }
}
@Component
class B {
   int execute(int i){
     return i;
   }
}
```

Now when I'm trying to mock the method execute, it is throwing nullPointer

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ATest{
  @InjectMocks
  A a;
  @Mock
  B b;

  @Test
  doStuffTest(){
   when(b.execute(anyInt()).thenReturn(1);
   assertEquals(1,a.doStuff());
 }
```

}

It is throwing NullPointer Exception on line `when(b.execute(anyInt()).thenReturn(1);`

Comment: instead of `AnyInt` try to use `nullable(Integer.class)` that accept null mock values

Comment: Still it's throwing nullpointer

Comment: if NPE is thrown on that line it looks like `b` is null, try setting mock manualy using `mock(B.class)`, and setting it manualy in `a`

Comment: Which `@Test` annotation are you using. Make sure you aren't mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5 annotations as that is trouble waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` annotation is part of Spring, while `@Mock` is part of Mockito. `@Autowired` will not be triggered using the Mockito test. Mocked class has to be a constructor where object can be injected by `@InjectMock`.

If you want to use `@Autowired` you need a Spring context like `@SpringBootTest` or others that scan and configuration your project. So, if you would like to mock this **bean**, you will have to `@MockBean` annotation.

Comment: But ``@Mock`` is working on other methods which are taking input from the user instead of hardcoded input as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` annotation, without that it's failing